Movie about three brothers separated by the state
Sorry this is a little generic and hazy. I think some of the details are specific enough to pin this down though. Please help identify this movie.
Three brothers were taken away by the state and separated. I can't remember if they were taken away from the mother or if she died and left them alone. The oldest continually fought for them to be back together. He might have been about 12 at the time.
One of them (I believe he was also the oldest) was treated as retarded and kept in a mental hospital although I don't believe he really was in any way. This was set in about the 1950s or 1960s when they still performed sterilizations. He was also beaten at some point and afterward walked with a limp. The other two probably ended up in foster homes and orphanages.
It took some twenty years for them all to be reunited after they were all older with families of their own. I think one of the wives was pivotal in this and possibly had to coerce a government employee to reveal some of the information. They meet again in the final scene and I remember it happening outside in a park.
I believe I watched this somewhere in the mid to late 1980s. It was definitely on television and probably not on a cable channel.

Was it a Hindi movie.

@Darren No, it was definitely an American movie.

Could it be After the Promise (TV Movie 1987)

Elmer Jackson is a carpenter in a small Californian town in the 1930s. Struggling to bring up 4 young boys after the death of his wife, he is horrified when the Government (citing trumped-up charges of parental neglect) places the boys into various foster homes and institutions, unaware of the abuse that boys would then be subjected to. The conditions imposed by the court and the difficulties caused by the Depression make Jackson's determined and vigorous quest to find his boys extremely difficult.





Looks like that's the one! And I forgot to mention that I thought it was based on a true story. I'll accept after I have the chance to watch a little longer and make sure. Thx.
